# Javascript: push array onto array with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Please explain this to me.  I'm trying to create an array of arrays with a for loop.  When it didn't work, I tried simplifying the code to understand what Javascript is doing, but the simple code doesn't make sense either.

```
function test(){
    var sub_array = [];
    var super_array =[];
    for (var i=1;i<=3;i++){
        sub_array.push(i);
        super_array.push(sub_array);
    }
    alert(super_array);
}
```

I expect to see [1; 1,2; 1,2,3].
Instead I get [1,2,3; 1,2,3; 1,2,3].
I get the same phenomenon if I loop 0-2 and assign by index.

Answer (score 18):

You're always pushing a reference to the same array into your super-array.

To solve that problem, you can use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to clone the sub-array before pushing it:

```
function test() {
    var sub_array = [];
    var super_array = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        sub_array.push(i);
        super_array.push(sub_array.slice(0));
    }
    alert(super_array);
}
```

**EDIT:** As Dan D. rightfully points out below, you can also call [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) without arguments instead of `slice(0)`. It's faster according to [this article](http://swingpants.com/2009/03/12/fastest-way-to-copy-an-array-concat-or-slice0/) (I did not measure it myself):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    sub_array.push(i);
    super_array.push(sub_array.concat());
}
```

Comment: why did you chose to use `.slice(0)` to copy the Array rather than `.concat()`? which may be faster but the profiling i did i wasn't sure of.

Comment: Interesting, according to [this blog](http://swingpants.com/2009/03/12/fastest-way-to-copy-an-array-concat-or-slice0/) `concat()` is faster. I'll mention it in my answer. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: This solution just saved me from tearing my hair out. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When you push "sub_array", you're not pushing a *copy* of it. You end up with the same array three times in "super_array". (I should say that you're pushing a *reference* to the same array three times.)

You could do this:

```
    // ...
    super_array.push(sub_array.slice(0));
```

to make a copy.

Answer (score 3):

well. You have to understand, that Array, Objects, Functions, etc. are references in javascript (only Numbers(Int,Floats,etc) and Strings are passed "by-value", which means, that the value is copied/duplicated)!
if you have an `var a=[];`, und say `var b=a` and add `b.push("bla")`, then alerting a, will show you the "bla" entry, even though you added it to b.
In other words; a and b is to javascript like a note on the frige from mom saying "the sandwhich on the left is for you." And then you know, that to take the left one and not just any random sandwich from the fridge. She also could have written another note (variable b) on your house' door, so that you knew where to go and look for the sandwich if you are in a hurry.
If she would have stuck a sandwich to the door.. well, that would be ackward. And JS thinks the same about it :)

so the solution to your problem is as fallows;

```
function test(){
    var super_array =[];
    for (var i=1;i<=3;i++){
        var subarray=[];
        for (var u=1;u<=4-i;u++){
            sub_array.push(u);
            super_array.push(subarray);
        }
    }
    alert(super_array);
}
```

by redefining the subarray, you create a new reference. So that the variable b (the second note on the hous' door) now points in the direction of a different sandwich - maybe dad's sandwich.

I hope I could help you understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are pushing the same array into super_array for each iteration in the for-loop. Try instead the following:

```
function test(){
    var sub_array = [];
    var super_array =[];
    for (var i=1;i<=3;i++){
        sub_array = sub_array.slice(0,sub_array.length);
        sub_array.push(i);
        super_array.push(sub_array);
    }
    alert(super_array);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using slice, although you don't need to pass in any parameters when you're using it to clone the entire array arr.slice() === arr.slice(0,arr.length)

Answer (score 0):

It is same sub_array that you are adding to the super_array. So why it has to be different.

You are not creating a new array and pushing into a super_array.

Answer (score 0):

`sub_array` is stored as a reference in `super_array` this means that when you change `sub_array` the change is reflected inside `super_array`